# Filter fields by expression arcpy

Tags: arcpy, python, pyqgis, cursor, python-script-tool

I have to trasform a script (which I didn't write myself) from QGIS to ArcMap.

In the script a filter by expression is used. The function has the input inl (= the layer with the data that should be filtered) and filter (a string e.g. 'HQ_SZEN<=30' / '"HQ_SZEN"<=30'). This filter is a user input and in QGIS one has to use the second form. I think ArcMap requires the same input but it didn't seem to work so I tried to use arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters with the first form like mentioned in example 4 here https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm. To use this I had to split the attributename from the actual expression and my reasoning was that there would always be a strange character between the name and the expression. So that is the reason why the arcpy code is kind of ugly with the chars_allowed_in_layername.

I was thinking of solving it by using arcpy.da.SearchCursor with a where clause but I can't get the filter to work. As filter i use 'HQ_SZEN <=30', the output I get is:

```
HQ_SZEN
<=30
"HQ_SZEN"<=30
No filter - filtering skipped
```

Main code:

```py
fifeatures = addAttrFactory().FilterInput(fl, filter)
        try:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Filter returned {0} rows".format(len(fifeatures)))
        except:
            arcpy.AddMessage("No filter - filtering skipped")
```

QGIS code:

```py
    def FilterInput(self,inl, filter):    
        ftext = ''
        if not filter or not filter.strip():
            #print "FilterInput()..." 
            featureIterator = inl.getFeatures()            
        else:     
            ftext = filter
            #print "FilterInput(%s) ..." % (ftext)
            featureIterator = inl.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( ftext))          

        #print "FilterInput(%s) done" % (ftext)
        return featureIterator
```

My ArcPy code:

```py
    def FilterInput(self, inl, filter):
        ftext = ''
        if not filter or not filter.strip():
            featureIterator = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inl, '*')
        else:
            chars_allowed_in_layername = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_0123456789"
            for char in filter:
                if char not in chars_allowed_in_layername:
                    end_layername = filter.index(char)-1
            name = filter[:end_layername].strip(' ')
            arcpy.AddMessage(name) #with input HQ_SZEN<=30: HQ_SZEN
            filter_expr = filter[end_layername:]
            arcpy.AddMessage(filter_expr) #with input HQ_SZEN<=30: <=30
            ftext = u'{0}'.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(inl, name)) + filter_expr
            arcpy.AddMessage(ftext) #with input HQ_SZEN<=30: "HQ_SZEN"<=30
            featureIterator = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inl, '*', where_clause=ftext)

        return featureIterator
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain the exact `filter` contents and the error or other result which makes it not work.

Comment: Suggested edits done

Comment: No, you stripped out the error message with the try/except.  Take out the try block and you'll know what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off course after I've asked the question I know the answer. After using Searchcursor I still have to iterate through it.
Changed the last line in the else to this and it works:

```py
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inl, '*', where_clause=ftext) as feats:
                featureIterator = []
                for f in feats:
                    featureIterator.append(f)
```

EDIT: just using quotation marks in the input (so filter = '"HQ_SZEN"<=30') is acceptable in my script and it makes the code a lot cleaner because all the stuff about extracting the fieldname from the filter becomes unnecessary.

This is the ArcPy result:

```py
    def FilterInput(self, inl, filter):
        if not filter or not filter.strip():
            featureIterator = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inl, '*')
        else:
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inl, '*', where_clause=filter) as feats:
                featureIterator = []
                for f in feats:
                    featureIterator.append(f)

        return featureIterator
```